# Is there a workaround for this Solve and NSolve error?

Tags: equation-solving, probability-or-statistics, distributions

Using either Solve or NSolve gives the same error:

```
epbest = ParetoDistribution[1796.5189215875334`, 1.2280269212105932`, 
0.32781656454399966`, 2273.547864479661`];
Solve[CDF[epbest, x] == 0.9750, x]
```

(*FactorSquareFree::lrgexp: Exponent is out of bounds for function FactorSquareFree.*)

Comment: `InverseCDF[epbest, 0.9750]`

Comment: also `Quantile[epbest, 0.9750]`

Comment: Why the downvote though? This seems an OK question, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An explicit approach is to note that the inverse CDF for a Pareto distribution with parameters `k`, `α`, `γ`, and `μ` for some cumulative probability `p` is

```
invParetoCDF[p_, k_, α_, γ_, μ_] := k (-1 + (1 - p)^(-1/α))^γ + μ

invParetoCDF[0.975, 1796.5189215875334`, 1.2280269212105932`, 
  0.32781656454399966`, 2273.547864479661`]
(* 7003.46 *)
```